# State Update is not reflecting immediately . How to use dependency array for useEffect to show changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, setstate

State Update is not reflecting immediately , how to get useEffect show changes in render function upon state update , I want render to show changes made when I load the page , that is on mount , even though the array is updated , it doesnt reflect .

```
const state = useContext(GlobalState)
const[jobs,setJobs]=state.categoriesAPI.jobs
const [user,setUser]=useState({})
useEffect( ()=>{

const  getmyUser=async ()=>{

         const {data:user}= await http.get(MyApiUrl+'/api/users/job')
         setUser(user)
        
        }
     
        const     populateJobs=async()=>{
         try{
         
           
         
             
               
               
               const myjobs=[...jobs];
               
               for(let i=0;i<myjobs.length;i++){
                 if(_.includes(user.saved,myjobs[i]._id)){
                 
                   myjobs[i].liked=true; // I WANT THIS CHANGE TO REFLECT IN RENDER fn() .
                 }
               }
              setJobs(myjobs)
     
     
         
               }
              catch(ex){
                  console.log('hey',ex)
              } 
         
             
             }

               getmyUser()
               populateJobs();
  


       

 
 },[])

even though the jobs array is  updated it doesnt reflect upon rendering ,
also if i use jobs in dependency array its getting into infinite loop ? how do I get to show it .
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a mutation problem. Although you create a new jobs array with `const myjobs=[...jobs];`, you create a shallow copy. This means that each job object inside the array remains the same instance as before the update, thus the `myjobs[i]` object is actually the same and does not trigger an update.

You should create a new copy of that object:

```js
 myjobs[i] = {...myjobs[i], liked: true};
```

Comment: Still the same problem .

Comment: Can you provide the full code? What is the implementation of `GlobalState` and how are `jobs` used in rendering?

Comment: https://github.com/gamercodes/stackoverflow  > Ive copied parts of it , please check .